# modelview and projection - which code is more common?

Tags: opengl

1.which code is more common and why? 
2. How will you describe the meaning of this code?

A.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0);
```

B.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

B.  It correctly separates the modelview/"camera"-type transforms from the projection matrix.

[There are some concerns with putting "camera"-type transforms in the projection matrix](http://sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html):

> - Lighting: OpenGL has to transform vertex normals into world coordinate
>     space - that is to say WITHOUT the effects of perspective - but WITH
>     the effects of the camera position. Hence, only the GL_MODELVIEW
>     matrix is applied to the normals for lighting. If you put the camera
>     transform into the GL_PROJECTION matrix then your lighting will be
>     wrong. However, some people do their own lighting - and in any case,
>     it can be a subtle error that you might not have noticed previously.
> - Fog: OpenGL has to figure out how far each vertex is from the camera.
>     Once again, perspective effects are not relevent to this calculation -
>     so the GL_PROJECTION matrix is not used. If you put the camera
>     transform into the GL_PROJECTION matrix then your fogging will be
>     wrong. Since few people use fog, many people have the error and don't
>     know it.
> - TexGen: Since OpenGL uses the eyepoint to figure out some of the
>     TexGen'ed texture coordinates, if the camera position is all mixed up
>     with the projection information then you'll end up with some pretty
>     strange texture coordinates. (Thanks to Brian Sharp at 3Dfx for
>     pointing this one out)